# Shop database, SQL for order table

Tags: sql

I have a University project and I have to create a DB for a plant shop.

I have a problem with the order table. At the moment it only allows a customer to buy one product at a time but in real life a customer can buy many products at a time.

For example,
We have a customer John Doe, and he buys two products that are in the product table. How do I pull those two (or more) products and add them to one order table?

Below is the SQL code I wrote:

```
CREATE TABLE customer(
    customer_id INT(3),
    customer_fname VARCHAR(20),
    customer_lname VARCHAR(20),
    customer_gender CHAR(1),
    customer_tel VARCHAR(20),
    customer_email VARCHAR(30),
    customer_dateJoined DATE,
    address_id INT(3),

    PRIMARY KEY(customer_id),
    INDEX(customer_id),
    FOREIGN KEY(customer_id)  REFERENCES address);


CREATE TABLE address(
    adress_id INT(3),
    customer_street VARCHAR(30),
    customer_town VARCHAR(30),
    customer_postcode CHAR(7),

    PRIMARY KEY(address_id),
    INDEX(address_id),
    FOREIGN KEY(address_id)  REFERENCES customer(address_id),
    FOREIGN KEY(address_id) REFERENCES employee(address_id));


CREATE TABLE product(
    product_id INT(5),
    product_name VARCHAR(20),
    product_season VARCHAR(15),
    product_price NUMERIC(4,2), 
    product_origin VARCHAR(15),
    product_type VARCHAR(15),
    product_inStock BOOLEAN,

    PRIMARY KEY(product_id),
    INDEX(product_id));


CREATE TABLE orders(
    order_id INT(3),
    customer_id INT(3),
    employee_id INT(3),
    product_name VARCHAR(20),
    quantity INT(4),
    order_date TIMESTAMP,

    PRIMARY KEY(order_id),
    INDEX(order_id));


CREATE TABLE employee(
    employee_id INT(3),
    employee_fname VARCHAR(20),
    employee_lname VARCHAR(20),
    address_id INT (3),
    employee_pay NUMERIC(2,2),
    employee_daysOff INT(2),
    employee_hoursWorked INT(3),

    PRIMARY KEY(staff_id),
    INDEX(staff_id));
```

Comment: create `OrderDetails` table to add multiple order lines

Comment: Have you made any attempts to solve this? Do you have any idea of what you need to do?

Comment: Yes, I have made an attempt to solve this and that's the sql code I wrote and posted. I don' know how to solve it therefore I asked this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create Kettle Table `customer_orders`, in this table you store `customer_id` and `order_id` and connect them with foreign keys to the customer and orders tables.

Like in the following query:

```sql
CREATE TABLE customer_orders(
  customer_id INT(3),
  order_id INT(3),
  PRIMARY KEY(customer_id, order_id),
  FOREIGN KEY(customer_id) REFERENCES customer(customer_id),
  FOREIGN KEY(order_id) REFERENCES orders(order_id)
);
```

Comment: So I would have a table containing all orders? Let's say we have a customer that orders 2 products, therefore, we will add two rows to the ORDERS_CUSTOMER table? But later we have second customer that orders 3 products, therefore, adding three more rows to the ORDERS_CUSTOMER table? So in the end the table would contain 5 rows?

Comment: Yes. You also need to make the PK of all your tables large and remove the customerid from the primary key of the Order table.

Comment: Yes, I think the customer_id will get repeated (one customer order two products but they are represented as two rows?) so we should remove it. Could you tell what you mean by make Primary Key large?

Comment: But imagine a very large shop like Amazon. I doubt they would store hundreds of thousands orders in one table. There probably would have a separate table containing orders for one user/customer and this is what I'm trying to resolve.

Comment: a table for every customer is far more inefficient

Comment: they probably create customer_orders tables depending on the location of the customers f.e. customers_orders_florida

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE sales.stores (
    store_id INT IDENTITY (1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
    store_name VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
    phone VARCHAR (25),
    email VARCHAR (255),
    street VARCHAR (255),
    city VARCHAR (255),
    state VARCHAR (10),
    zip_code VARCHAR (5)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to design this is to have two tables for Orders.

1. **OrderHeader** :- This contains order id with customer details.
2. **OrderItem**  :- Contains Line items per order.

> ```
>     OrderHeader fields could be 
>     order_id   //primary key
>     customer_id 
>     employee_id 
>     order_date 
>
>     OrderItem :- Fields could be 
>     order_id    //composite key
>     line_Item_id  //composite key
>     product_id,
>     product_quant
> ```